# Exim cannot receive any email but can send

Tags: email, exim

I had defect on exim that i could not send any email! I'm using Redstation's servers and they told me put these lines to exim.conf :

```
smarthost:
driver = manualroute
domains = *
transport = remote_smtp
route_data = "relay.redstationmail.co.uk"
```

It fixed my problem to send out emails , but now i cannot receive any email!

This is error log for sending email to my server by yahoo :

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  manager@(mydomain).ir

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>
Received: from relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk ([37.157.240.34])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg8-00064W-Vv
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:40 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 33B4E161D8E
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:12 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309099; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:54 +0000
Received: from relay6out.redstationmail.co.uk ([81.94.193.130])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg8-00064P-Jn
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:40 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay6out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id DD95D84DCE
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:11 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309098; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:53 +0000
Received: from relay1out.redstationmail.co.uk ([5.152.192.122])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com.com>)
    id 1ULvg7-00064I-Uh
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:39 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay1out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3F202138BEE
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:11 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309097; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:52 +0000
Received: from relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk ([37.157.240.34])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg7-00064B-I6
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:39 -0400
Received: from relay3in (relay3in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.3])
    by relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id BFDE8161D8E
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:10 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay3in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309096; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:50 +0000
Received: from relay2out.redstationmail.co.uk ([31.3.243.98])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg7-000644-5f
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:39 -0400
Received: from relay3in (relay3in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.3])
    by relay2out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id B382EC0971
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:10 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay3in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309094; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:49 +0000
Received: from relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk ([37.157.240.34])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg6-00063x-OM
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:38 -0400
Received: from relay3in (relay3in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.3])
    by relay3out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id DACCC161D8E
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:09 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay3in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309092; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:49 +0000
Received: from relay1out.redstationmail.co.uk ([5.152.192.122])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg6-00063q-8q
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:38 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay1out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 90038138BEE
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:09 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309091; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:51 +0000
Received: from relay4out.redstationmail.co.uk ([37.220.0.94])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg5-00063j-RZ
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:37 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay4out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 258B61C2FD4
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:09 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309090; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:50 +0000
Received: from relay8out.redstationmail.co.uk ([77.245.79.122])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with esmtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg5-00063c-D6
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:37 -0400
Received: from relay2in (relay2in.redstationmail.co.uk [109.73.64.2])
    by relay8out.redstationmail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id B104A14364E
    for <manager@(mydomain).ir>; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:15:08 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from server.(mydomain).ir (81.94.201.114) by relay2in (Redstation ESMTP MAIL Service) with ESMTP id 69309089; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 01:18:50 +0000
Received: from nm16-vm0.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com ([98.139.212.253])
    by server.(mydomain).ir with smtp (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>)
    id 1ULvg4-00063V-OR
    for manager@(mydomain).ir; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 09:18:37 -0400
Received: from [98.139.215.143] by nm16.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 30 Mar 2013 13:18:47 -0000
Received: from [98.139.212.227] by tm14.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 30 Mar 2013 13:18:47 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1036.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 30 Mar 2013 13:18:47 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 74871.35214.bm@omp1036.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 46361 invoked by uid 60001); 30 Mar 2013 13:18:47 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=rocketmail.com; s=s1024; t=1364649526; bh=ZQa4f38qMUbc0EmcS8AM3gS2BmD/1mmEq70+bA9nTm0=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=taoGzPsfqQbjftVoTM3mfKZWf9YhLqus67eqx0nf8nJJ7j9XNi0Uk7eH4ey0RcGMEf1UhaS7VeOz+k7Xuh94gDr+G34GiLukJ9yX4pB+YnoYbCm1LArqEgysXIQcTAKKEhuVUdwekcXF+IEnHMsRJPGMfJVXcaLHmVkXwy6kqm0=
DomainKey-Signature:a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=s1024; d=rocketmail.com;
  h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
  b=1mAEJfHfRSjynPnZqRRJSOJF50TMF6gYoiQz07B1jvTOAX5FYJdIkF+hlvburm+xB5R7QnPijKrCp5ZdnDjiBJLTVMtc5P0/KLCy5YN2C6t1RoO9nDZlSrEenPBW7pG0j2SB27LmaarKbA7nJPwVvsLqwo829xKEnlIyYuw6QI8=;
X-YMail-OSG: rFXo.d4VM1lquCG8imSw3Y1OagaldS8yvwsckyHTbMqlALr
mpdFrRlibJ6MSH46QxSqj8BWor8v9ehdruUqXap0MJRMiRhm.UVih4D4E783
DOiN9.8txNsi8ykYCu5njT9lRfItu_O2otw.OHz4OeUZzCmwn5vfcJHYdeLh
wWfx.6TxhwkRrh.DsfGx0Yhj9xXt9JFgDuBeWSG6xS.mx8yjrX.leCbXJEs2
V7l14ThnHCs7396jEnZmXPwMWa5Z25KJgxcgKDQPjydDQ0jzYg96eCo78ahY
0Fg4k8kBRQO.0_PGgkxCZOquJPb93EB5zE7yDfnAh_uWehTR_sev2rcQVyPc
Xl9ChrbfhEGW.1X5WyVU.vRz04A_26AqLm34CKjMYSM6VXDvVd1poF3Q1RHB
5vMgKhQSpmqNIOpRaTJIygQrd6Z92EnvQBQnbmu66e8jbevs9E2y.8rRdcpK
FcDc4ODg-
Received: from [5.39.7.246] by web163104.mail.bf1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Sat, 30 Mar 2013 06:18:46 PDT
X-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 002.001,YXMKCsKgCl9fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fCkJlc3QgUmVnYXJkcy4KTXIuQWJiYXMgRmFyYWhtYW5kIQpfX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX18BMAEBAQE-
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.139.530
Message-ID: <1364649526.44841.YahooMailNeo@web163104.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>
Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 06:18:46 -0700 (PDT)
From: Abbas (mydomain) <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>
Reply-To: Abbas (mydomain) <a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com>
Subject: a
To: "manager@(mydomain).ir" <manager@(mydomain).ir>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-65459842-412224943-1364649526=:44841"
```

And This is /var/log/exim/rejectlog

```
2013-03-28 13:03:46 H=nm17-vm0.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com [98.139.213.157] F=<a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com> rejected RCPT <admi@(mydomain).ir>:
2013-03-29 03:17:52 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:52 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:54 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:55 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:56 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:57 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:58 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:17:59 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:18:00 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:18:01 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=tccefsfg)
2013-03-29 03:18:02 login authenticator failed for (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mwcgdsh)
2013-03-29 03:18:02 SMTP call from (PC0701HPF) [14.222.44.85] dropped: too many nonmail commands (last was "AUTH")
2013-03-29 08:09:19 H=nm28-vm0.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com [98.139.213.149] F=<a.(mydomain)@rocketmail.com> rejected RCPT <admi@(mydomain).ir>:
2013-03-29 16:12:09 H=36-231-66-116.dynamic-ip.hinet.net (81.94.201.114) [36.231.66.116] F=<z2007tw@yahoo.com.tw> rejected RCPT <vkihwpdh@yahoo.com.tw>: authentication$
```

Comment: It looks as though your server is configured to require authentication even for email that should be delivered locally. If you post the relevant parts of the configuration, probably somebody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With current configuration you send **all** mail to smarthost, then it it's mail for your local domain then smarthost send it back to you, then you send to smarthost.... - you have mail routing loop for local mail.
You should change this smarthost router to:

```
smarthost:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_data = "relay.redstationmail.co.uk"
```

where `local_domains` is list of you local domains defined at the beginning of configuration like this:

```
domainlist local_domains=first.local.domain.com:second.local.domain.com
```

Comment: Also: 1) looks like rejectlog is not for this sample mail; 2) I know that nobody like spam, but you really should tell us real domain somewhere (if pre-mydomain version was real one then I don't see it in DNS)